# jQuery.on('keydown') when key is "enter" is being intercepted (?) and won't work

Tags: jquery, html, events, jquery-on

I am modifying a substantial existing application. In this application, at the top of the page there is a search bar. I need to record when the user presses "Enter" in the search bar so that I can fire some logic.

Simple enough, it seems. I can just use jQuery `keydown` or even `keypress` event to record the key that is pressed and then if the key value matches **13** for "Enter" I can proceed.

```
<form action="https://www.google.com" method="get" target="_blank">
    <input id="search-field"/>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).on('keydown', "#search-field", function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13)
        {
            //"some logic"
        }
    });
</script>
```

This captures every keypress *EXCEPT* "enter"! When I create an `alert(e.which);` in my JavaScript, each key's value will pop up, but when it I try "enter" it just submits the form and loads a new page without triggering the alert.

**My Question:** Without knowing the existing code regarding the search-box (I have very little access) is there any way that I can somehow get this `keydown` event to fire? Why might it be failing?

*Note:* I have to use jQuery.on() in this format to handle the event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figure out how to circumvent the other events process. But I did find what was preventing my key from being recognized:

In a file `Site.js` there was some JavaScript:

```
$('#SearchTerm').keydown(function (event)
    {
        return handleKey(event);
    });

    $('#SearchTerm').keyup(function (event)
    {
        // Some stuff here...
        return false;
    }
```

This file was included *before* the JavaScript file I had. Since it was first and had its own `keydown`/`keyup`events, it was executing them and doing its own `e.preventDefault()` before the keypress had a chance to get to my own script.

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent the normal behavior of the form. Use: `e.preventDefault()` in your logic to prevent the form to be submitted. Also, consider using the event `keyUp` instead.

Comment: e.preventDefault() in this event handler prevented everything except "Enter". Maybe something is accessing it before my event handler?

Comment: Or even afterwards. If the form submit is happening in another event such as "submit" or "keyUp", preventing on "keyDown" will not do a thing. You can stop try to stop the event to bubble up to the parents elements by adding Search Results
e.stopPropagation();

Comment: Maybe try stopping the propagation too? I am not too sure but it might be that the keydown is being propagated to the <form>

Comment: Even adding `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` to the event don't prevent the form from submitting or let me grab my enter.click(). It prevents other keys such as "backspace" from operating but **enter** is still being intercepted somewhere and it won't register in my function that it is pressed. WHO KNOWS WHAT'S GOIN ON